# How to trigger get data from localstorage after updated variable ? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

***the data used fis updated — and then it is executed to me.***

Better explain problem:

login component get

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand the question nor the assignment `this.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));` after it's assigned the `data`. Nevertheless the API calls are asynchronous. To make any statements after the API responds, you need to include it in the subscription callbacks. You could learn more about async data [here](http://he%20API%20calls%20are%20asynchronous).

```js
getUserInfo() {
  this.subscription.push(
    this.userService.getInfo().subscribe(
      data => {
        if(data) {
          this.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  );
}
```

Perhaps if you could provide more details, the `subscription` array could be removed as well. Instead you could use RxJS [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/takeUntil) operator to close open subscriptions.

```js
completed$ = new Subject<any>();

getUserInfo() {
  this.userService.getInfo().pipe(
    takeUntil(this.completed$)       // <-- complete when `completed$` emits
  ).subscribe(
    data => {
      if(data) {
        this.userInfo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"));
      }
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err)
    }
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.completed$.next();            // <-- emit here to close active subscriptions
  this.completed$.complete();
}
```

Comment: Like I said, you need to provide more details. Using `localStorage` to share data between components isn't a good idea. We could use a singleton service for it.

Comment: Hi namesake i am update question. If already not understand i will try to better explain @Michael D